# Modifying angular.json Angular 6+ to load scripts in index.html correctly

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I am running an angular project on my computer:

Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 11.6.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.1.4

I have updated angular from 4.5.5 to 7.1.4.

Now I get the following error in my console in my chrome browser:

> 9 GET http://localhost:3000/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So it can't find the script in my index.html (See below)

But when I have a look at my folder in my dev environment I can find the files and the path seems correct too:

[image: Screenshot Folder Public]
![two muppets][1]

My backend is in Node.js and app.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = require('./router'),
    templates = require('./views/templates');

// Setup
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
router(app);

templates.initSync();

// Start server
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Kommis back-end is running on port', port);
});

// Catch unhandled promise rejections, see
// https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-    v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
        console.log(err.stack);
    });

module.exports = app;
```

This is my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Digitaler Tischplan</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

> I realized I had to add to the base ref `gen/` then it works!

But how can I change the output of the generated angular code so that it works, without modifying it afterward?

I had a look before I did the Angular update the scripts in the index.html file are stated like this:

`gen/scriptname.js`

Why is it not doing it anymore?

These are my first lines of the angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-src": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
         "build": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
           "options": {
             "outputPath": "../public/gen/",
             "index": "src/index.html",
             "main": "src/main.ts",
             "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
             "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "assets": [
                "src/assets",
                "src/favicon.ico"
             ],
              "styles": [
               "src/css/main.scss"
              ],
              "scripts": []
            },
```

> In order to build the angular application correctly I had to `gen/` in the `index.html` in the angular-src.

Comment: try to full path to the scripts also don't add all the scripts in a single line. it's hard to read and more likely to make mistakes or spot them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did apply full path but it does not help.

Comment: I realized I had to add to the base ref `gen/`then it works!